# Sony Cybershot DSC HX60V And Remote API

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I have seen a lot of remote API questions and replies about Sony Camera Remote API.However, I was not able to find the solution to my issue. I have Japanese version of Sony-HX60V. Based on Remote API docs, it is supporting HTTP Api. I connected my PC to camera's Wi-Fi (10.0.0.1) and I verified that my PC can ping/access camera. I have written an ssdp client. However, whenever I set Search Target as following, I cannot get any information from camera.

```
urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1
```

I investigated all the messages that I was able to get from my camera. I was only be able to get DmsDesc.xml, DmsDescPush.xml, CmsDesc.xml and CdsDesc.xml. None of those xmls contain any information about scalar web api. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of information you are trying to get from the Camera?  Also, since you mention that you have looked at the docs I assume you have already downloaded the Camera Remote SDK and taken a look at how the sample projects work?  https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Comment: Thanks for your concern Marlin, I have found that issue was based on wrong menu entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question. 
I was trying to connect to camera through direct wi-fi connection. However, when I try to connect with application connection (i.e. PlayMobile) in camera menu, I was able to get correct replies to my SSDP requests.